# getopt, getopts or manual parsing - what to use when I want to support both short and long options?

Tags: bash, shell-script, options, user-interface, getopts

Currently I'm writing a Bash script which has the following requirements:

- it should run on a wide variety of Unix/Linux platforms
- it should support both short and (GNU) long options

I know that `getopts` would be the preferred way in terms of portability but AFAIK it doesn't support long options.

`getopt` supports long options but the [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035#Complex_nonstandard_add-on_utilities) recommends strongly against it:

> Never use getopt(1). getopt cannot handle empty arguments strings, or
>   arguments with embedded whitespace. Please forget that it ever
>   existed.

So, there still is the option of manual parsing. This is error-prone, produces quite some boilerplate code, and I need to handle errors by myself (I guess `getopt(s)` do error-handling by themselves).

So, what would be the preferred choice in this case?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash

Comment: `getopts` supports long options. You need to use the Korn Shell or the Bourne Shell.

Comment: While not your direct question, give thought to Perl 5, it's options modules are super easy to use and very effective, and allow full customization as well as behaving precisely how you expect options to work, they also allow for much better error handling. To me there are several red flags I use now to tell me to stop using shell script and switch to perl, options handling is one, length of script is another (> 50 lines or so, perl): Sample: use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions); Getopt::Long::Configure ('bundling', 'no_ignore_case', 
'no_getopt_compat', 'no_auto_abbrev','pass_through');

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If it has to be portable to a range of Unices, you'd have to stick to POSIX sh. And AFAIU there you just have no choice but rolling argument handling by hand.

Comment: `getopts` is a [POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/getopts.html). I agree though if scripts also need to run on Solaris etc. that do not have GNU bash and tools installed.

Comment: All shells that are decently written and call the C library function `getopt(3c)` for `getopts` include support for long options on Solaris.

Answer (score 42):

`getopt` vs `getopts` seems to be a religious issue. As for the arguments against `getopt` in the [Bash FAQ](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035#getopts):

- "`getopt` cannot handle empty arguments strings" seems to refer to a known issue with *optional* arguments, which it looks like `getopts` doesn't support at all (at least from reading `help getopts` for Bash 4.2.24). From `man getopt`:

  > getopt(3) can parse long options with optional arguments that are given an empty optional argument (but can not do this for short options). This getopt(1) treats optional arguments that are empty as if they were not present.

Many "traditional"  implementations of `getopt` indeed cannot parse arguments with embedded whitespace, but that's not the case with the one from util-linux or the one included in Busybox:

- test.sh:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env bash
  getopt -T
  if [ "$?" != 4 ]; then
      echo 2>&1 "Wrong version of 'getopt' detected, exiting..."
      exit 1
  fi
  set -o errexit -o noclobber -o nounset -o pipefail
  params="$(getopt -o ab:c -l alpha,bravo:,charlie --name "$0" -- "$@")"
  eval set -- "$params"

  while true
  do
      case "$1" in
          -a|--alpha)
              echo alpha
              shift
              ;;
          -b|--bravo)
              echo "bravo=$2"
              shift 2
              ;;
          -c|--charlie)
              echo charlie
              shift
              ;;
          --)
              shift
              break
              ;;
          *)
              echo "Not implemented: $1" >&2
              exit 1
              ;;
      esac
  done
  ```
- run:

  ```
  $ ./test.sh -
  $ ./test.sh -acb '   whitespace   FTW   '
  alpha
  charlie
  bravo=   whitespace   FTW   
  $ ./test.sh -ab '' -c
  alpha
  bravo=
  charlie
  $ ./test.sh --alpha --bravo '   whitespace   FTW   ' --charlie
  alpha
  bravo=   whitespace   FTW   
  charlie
  ```

Of course the portability issue still stands; you'll have to decide how much time is worth investing in platforms without that version of `getopt`. My own tip is to use the [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) and [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) guidelines - Only develop for those specific platforms which you know are going to be used. Shell code portability generally goes to 100% as development time goes to infinity.

Comment: The OP mentioned the need to be portable to many Unix platforms while the `getopt` you're quoting here is Linux-specific. Note that `getopt` is not part of `bash`, it's not even a GNU utility and on Linux is shipped with the util-linux package.

Comment: I don't think the OP would be asking this if `getopt` was not available.

Comment: Most platforms have `getopt`, only Linux AFAIK comes with one that supports long options or blanks in arguments. The other ones would only support the System V syntax.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Also, I thought it was clear that `getopt` is not part of Bash since it's got a separate `man` page.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas The original argument still stands: OP wouldn't be asking about pros and cons of a feature unless that feature is supported on the relevant platforms. It seems obvious that the choice is between a `getopt` which supports `-l`, `getopts` or something completely different.

Comment: `getopt` is a traditional command that comes from System V long before Linux was ever released. `getopt` was never standardised. None of POSIX, Unix, or Linux (LSB) ever standardized the `getopt` command. `getopts` is specified in all three but without support for long options.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7297/discussion-between-l0b0-and-stephane-chazelas)

Comment: You specified `b` as having a _required_ option.  Two colons (e.g. `::`) specify an optional argument.

Comment: Just to add to this discussion: this is not the traditional `getopt`. It is the linux-utils flavor as indicated by @StéphaneChazelas. It has legacy options that will disable the syntax described above, in particular the manpage states "GETOPT_COMPATIBLE forces getopt to use the first calling format as specified in the SYNOPSIS". However if you can expect target systems to have this package installed this is totally the way to go, as the original getopt is awful and Bash's getopt is very limited

Comment: OP's link that claims "Traditional versions of getopt cannot handle empty argument strings, or arguments with embedded whitespace." and that the util-linux version of getopt shouldn't be used has no evidence and is no longer accurate.  A quick survey (5+ years later) shows that the default version of getopt available from ArchLinux, SUSE, Ubuntu, RedHat, Fedora, and CentOS (as well as most derivative variants) all support optional arguments and arguments with whitespace.

Comment: Coming from a place of ignorance here, but that's also why I ask. The `eval` when setting the positional parameters, can that be exploited to inject code?

Comment: @leo, no, the "non-traditional", or "extended" getopt's (util-linux and Busybox, as far as I've found) support a mode where they produce shell-quoted output, which can and has to be read in with `eval`. But you also have to use them right, and test beforehand (with `getopt -T`) that you have one of those versions, because the "traditional" ones may run with the same syntax, but do things differently... Compare the output of e.g. `getopt a: -- -a "foo bar"` (trad.) and `getopt -o a: -- -a "foo bar"` (better) with different versions of `getopt`.

Answer (score 12):

There's this [getopts_long](http://stchaz.free.fr/getopts_long.sh) written as a POSIX shell function that you may embed inside your script.

Note that the Linux `getopt` (from `util-linux`) works correctly when not in *traditional* mode and supports long options, but is probably  not an option for you if you need to be portable to other Unices.

Recent versions of ksh93 (`getopts`) and zsh (`zparseopts`) have built-in support for parsing long options which might be an option for you as those are available for most Unices (though often not installed by default).

Another option would be to use `perl` and its `Getopt::Long` module both of which should be available on most Unices nowadays, either by writing the whole script in `perl` or just call perl just to parse the option and feed the extracted information to the shell. Something like:

```
parsed_ops=$(
  perl -MGetopt::Long -le '

    @options = (
      "foo=s", "bar", "neg!"
    );

    Getopt::Long::Configure "bundling";
    $q="'\''";
    GetOptions(@options) or exit 1;
    for (map /(\w+)/, @options) {
      eval "\$o=\$opt_$_";
      $o =~ s/$q/$q\\$q$q/g;
      print "opt_$_=$q$o$q"
    }' -- "$@"
) || exit
eval "$parsed_ops"
# and then use $opt_foo, $opt_bar...
```

See `perldoc Getopt::Long` for what it can do and how it differs from other option parsers.

Answer (score 6):

Every discussion on this matter highlight the option to write the parsing code manually - only then you can be sure about the functionality and portability. I advise you not to write code that you can have generated and re-generated by easy-to-use  open-source code generators. Use [Argbash](https://argbash.io), which has been designed to provide the definitive answer to your problem. It is a [well-documented](http://argbash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) code generator available as a [command-line application](https://github.com/matejak/argbash/releases/latest), [online](https://argbash.io/generate) or as a [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/matejak/argbash/).

I advise against bash libraries, some of them use `getopt` (which makes quite unportable) and it is a pain to bundle a gigantic unreadable shell blob with your script.

Comment: Argbash link is incorrect, should be https://argbash.dev/

Answer (score 1):

You could use `getopt` on systems that support it and use a fall back for systems that don't.

For instance  [`pure-getopt`](https://github.com/agriffis/pure-getopt/) is implemented in pure Bash to be a drop-in replacement for GNU `getopt`.