# bash error on eval containing blank space

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, variable, whitespace

I need to triggeer a bash passing parameter with a format [ variable_name="value" ] like this:

```
./test.sh ip='164.130.21.98' hostname='whatever' pwd='/test' ftpcmd='CWD debug' user='stefano'
```

On test.sh script I want to assign to any variable the relevant value:

```
#!/bin/bash
eval `echo "$@"`
echo $ftpcmd
```

But I get a `prova: command not found` error.

I cannot understand what's wrong on my `ftpcmd='CWD debug'` parameter neither how I should write it instead.

If I try to replace eval with declare then the `$ftpcmd` is set only to `CWD` instead of `CWD debug` as I'm expecting.

Comment: don't reinvent the wheel.  option parsing was done years ago.  use `getopts` (bash built-in, short single-letter options only) or `/usr/bin/getopt` (from util-linux, supports both short and --long options)

Comment: see: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62950/getopt-getopts-or-manual-parsing-what-to-use-when-i-want-to-support-both-shor

Comment: @cas you're right. As I wrote I've still many things to learn on bash scripting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put the assignments *before* the script

```
ip='164.130.21.98' hostname='whatever' pwd='/test' ftpcmd='CWD debug' user='stefano' ./test.sh
```

the variables are available in the script's environment. The `-k` option treats *all* assignments, not just pre-command assignments, as environment modifications.

```
set -k
./test.sh ip='164.130.21.98' hostname='whatever' pwd='/test' ftpcmd='CWD debug' user='stefano'
set +k
```

In either case, `eval` is not required at all and can be removed.

Comment: In such case your suggestion is to have to to a parent shell that runs test.sh. Am I right?

Comment: For the first example (`x=1 y="abc" ./cmd.sh`), no, you are simply reordering the command.