# How to include custom command options in a bash script with $1 and $2?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, scripting, arguments

I have a script `myscript.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

echo $1 $2
```

which is used something like ...

```
./myscript.sh foo bar
```

which gives me an output of ...

```
foo bar
```

---

but how can i make this script include custom command options? for example ...

```
./myscript.sh -a foo and corespond to $1
```

and

```
./myscript.sh -b bar and corespond to $2
```

Comment: There's a [great Q&A on StackOverflow that covers your options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash/14203146#14203146) in some detail.

Comment: @Seamus now I know where they all get the useless quoting of the case variable and of the `a:bc:`optstring from (but do not care to quote arithm or other var expansions). They're cut&pasting from "great" Q&As.

Comment: @UncleBilly: "There is nothing new under the sun" :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are listing bash as the shell used, type:

```
$ help getopts
```

Which will print something like:

> getopts: getopts optstring name [arg]
>       Parse option arguments.
>
> Getopts is used by shell procedures to parse positional parameters as options.
>
> OPTSTRING contains the option letters to be recognized; if a letter is followed by a
>   colon, the option is expected to have an argument, which should be separated from it by white space.
>
> Each time it is invoked, getopts will place the next option in the shell variable $name, initializing name if it does not exist, and the index of the next argument to be processed into the shell variable OPTIND.  OPTIND is initialized to 1 each time the shell or a shell script is invoked.  When an option requires an argument, getopts places that argument into the shell variable OPTARG.
>
> Getopts normally parses the positional parameters ($0 - $9), but if more arguments are given, they are parsed instead.

Related:

1. [Getopts tutorial.](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial)
2. [getopts How to pass command line options](http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/08/getopts-how-to-pass-command-line-options-shell-script-Linux.html)
3. [How to use getopts in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483119/an-example-of-how-to-use-getopts-in-bash)
4. [Getopt, getopts or manual parsing?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62950/getopt-getopts-or-manual-parsing-what-to-use-when-i-want-to-support-both-shor)

Answer (score 5):

You should to use [man 1 bash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

Small example:

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts "a:b:" opt      # get options for -a and -b ( ':' - option has an argument )
do
    case $opt in
        a) echo "Option a: $opt, argument: $OPTARG";;
        b) echo "Option b: $opt, argument: $OPTARG";;
    esac
done
```

Comment: A small example is like a picture, worth a thousand words!

Comment: Assuming you can read code and it's got comments lol

Comment: @roaima I've add man page about `getopt` (I hurried with answer) but example was about `getopts`. I omitted `:` also. That`s why I've been downvoted. I think so. Maybe the problem in something else.

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk maybe because [man 1 bash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) is not [man 1 getopts](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getopt.1.html) ? That being said, I upvoted you! I also appreciated the man 1 bash link as it would do me very well to read it. So thanks my man! :)