# Parsing Arguments in Bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have a script which basically parses a file. 
While executing this script i want to set two flags.

These are my two cases:
I want to set `--hello-you` as a flag which then takes two mandatory arguments after it:  `./script.sh --hello-you <FILE> <PATH>`

I want `-h or --help` to provide help manual.
`./script.sh --help` or `./script.sh -h`
I know that -h or --help is easy by casing $1 but the problem is that when user preses `--hello-you` the program recognizes same as `-h`

Comment: Possibly related: [getopt, getopts or manual parsing - what to use when I want to support both short and long options?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62950/getopt-getopts-or-manual-parsing-what-to-use-when-i-want-to-support-both-shor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be best to forget about long-options and simply use `getopts` to do this but otherwise you can loop through your positional parameters similar to:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

usage () {
    cat <<EOF >&2
    Usage: $(basename "$0") [-h] --hello-you FILE PATH
EOF
    exit 1
}

while (($#)); do 
    case $1 in
        --hello-you)
            file=$2
            path=$3
            shift 2
            [[ -z "$file" || -z "$path" ]] && usage
        ;;
        -h|--help)  usage;;
        *)          usage;;
    esac
    shift
done

echo "File is $file"
echo "Path is $path"
```

---

I'm not sure what you tried before but case won't interpret `--hello-you` as `-h`.  Maybe your case had something like `--h*)`?

Additionally this is only checking that `file` and `path` are set and not that they are files but you may want to do that depending on whether or not you expect them to exist before the script is run.  It also doesn't require `--hello-you` be set at all because it isn't clear if that was your intent.