# Typical syntax for optional script arguments

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am writing some scripts in bash and other languages and I am always confused (this might be due to different syntax of various tools I have used in the past): what is the most generally accepted syntax for optional command line parameters?

Should I use `--my-parameter 10` or `-mypar10` or `--my-parameter=10` or `-mypar=10` or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Posix** recommends some [*Program Argument Syntax Conventions*](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html):

e.g.:

> Option names are single alphanumeric characters

so, for you this means to use:

```
-p 10
```

or the equivalent

```
-p10
```

(`p` for `my(p)arameter`, you could of course use `m` if you prefer).

**GNU** adds long options to the convention:

> Long options consist of ‘--’ followed by a name made of alphanumeric characters and dashes. Option names are typically one to three words long, with hyphens to separate words

```
--my-parameter=10
```

---

`--my-parameter 10`, `-mypar10` and `-mypar=10` are not valid within these conventions.

---

For shell scripts, you might want to use `getopt`/`getopts` to do the parsing and validation for you.

See:

- [Using getopts to process long and short command line options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-to-process-long-and-short-command-line-options/7948533#7948533)
- [getopt, getopts or manual parsing - what to use when I want to support both short and long options?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62950/getopt-getopts-or-manual-parsing-what-to-use-when-i-want-to-support-both-shor)

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning the shell built-in `getopts`, and `getopt` (on some platforms) to handle long options. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7948533/2344631) over on StackOverflow