# Handling long-options with getopts

Tags: bash, getopts, eval, set

I am parsing options with `getopts` but would like to handle long-options as well.

```
print-args ()
{
 title="$1" ; shift
 printf "\n%s\n" "${title}: \$@:"
 for arg in "$@"; do
   (( i = i + 1 ))
   printf "%s |%s|\n" "${i}." "$arg"
 done
}

getopts_test ()
{
 aggr=()
 for arg in "$@"; do
   case $arg in
    ("--colour"|"--color")     aggr+=( "-c" ) ;;
    ("--colour="*|"--color="*) aggr+=( "-c" "${arg#*=}" ) ;;
    (*)  aggr+=( "$arg" ) ;;
   esac
 done

 print-args "print" "$@"

 eval set -- "${aggr[@]}"
 print-args "eval" "$@"

 set -- "${aggr[@]}"
 print-args "set" "$@"

 local OPTIND OPTARG
 local shortopts="C:"
 while getopts "$shortopts" arg; do
   case $arg in
    ("c") context="$OPTARG" ;;
    (*) break ;;
   esac
 done
 shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ))
}
```

But I wonder whether the use of `set -- "${aggr[@]}"` is correct.

Or is the following (using `eval`) more appropriate?

```
eval set -- "${aggr[@]}"
```

I have performed a test shown below.  With eval, the string "Gunga Din" is split up, whereas with `set -- "${aggr[@]}"`, it is being parsed correctly as a single string.

```
getopts_test -f -g 130 --colour="170 20" "Gunga Din"

print: $@:
1. |-f|
2. |-g|
3. |130|
4. |--colour=170 20|
5. |Gunga Din|

eval: $@:
1. |-f|
2. |-g|
3. |130|
4. |-c|
5. |170|
6. |20|
7. |Gunga|
8. |Din|

set: $@:
1. |-f|
2. |-g|
3. |130|
4. |-c|
5. |170 20|
6. |Gunga Din|
```

Then I ran another function that uses the non-GNU `getopt`.

```
getopt_test ()
{
 shortopts="Vuhv::H::w::e::n::l::C:"
 shortopts="${shortopts}bgcrmo"
 longopts="version,usage,help,verbosity::"
 longopts="${longopts},heading::,warning::,error::"
 longopts="${longopts},blu,grn,cyn,red,mgn,org"
 
 opts=$( getopt -o "$shortopts" -l "$longopts" -n "${0##*/}" -- "$@" )

 print-args "\$@:" "$@"
 print-args "opts:" "$opts"

 set -- "$opts"
 print-args "set -- \"$opts\"" "$@"

 eval set -- "$opts"
 print-args "eval set -- \"$opts\"" "$@"

}
```

This resulted in the following

```
getopt_test --warning=3 "foo'bar" "Gunga Din"

$@:
1. |--warning=3|
2. |foo'bar|
3. |Gunga Din|

opts:
1. | --warning '3' -- 'foo'\''bar' 'Gunga Din'|

set -- "$opts"
1. | --warning '3' -- 'foo'\''bar' 'Gunga Din'|

eval set -- "$opts"
1. |--warning|
2. |3|
3. |--|
4. |foo'bar|
5. |Gunga Din|
```

As shown the result of getopt is a single entry with positional arguments re-arranged.  This shows the need to use `eval set -- "$opts"` to split the positional arguments in the `opts` string into five entries for option parsing and processing.

Comment: Do you have the GNU `getopt` tool? It'll handle quite a lot of this for you. (Here, `getopt --version` → `getopt from util-linux 2.33.1`)

Comment: @roaima, note that `util-linux` is not part of the GNU project.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I'd had the impression that the newer `getopt` was GNU

Comment: @roaima, no, it appears to be associated with the Linux kernel developers rather than GNU, at least as far as we believe wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Util-linux and e.g. the Debian package page also links to www.kernel.org: https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/util-linux

Answer (score 3):

The idea there is to preprocess the arguments and change each `--context` to `-C` which `getopts` can then process? I suppose that would work, but note that GNU-style long options can also take arguments in the format `--context=foobar`, and your construct here doesn't support that. The user would need to know that this particular tool here requires `--context` `foobar` as two distinct arguments. Or you'd need to make the preprocessing more complex.

You might also want to check all arguments that start with `--`, as otherwise e.g. a mistyped `--cotnext` would go to `getopts` as-is, and you'd get complaints about unknown options. (Or worse, wrong options would be enabled.)

> But I wonder whether the use of `set -- "${aggr[@]}"` is correct.
>
> Or is the following (using eval) more appropriate?

`set -- "${aggr[@]}"` expands the elements of the array, to distinct words, and then assigns those words to the positional parameters. Each array element will become exactly one positional parameter, without changes.

`eval set -- "${aggr[@]}"` would expand all the elements of the array, then join them together with spaces, prepend the `set --`  and evaluate the result as a shell command. That is, if you have the array elements `abc def`, `$(date >&2)`, `ghi'jkl`, the command would be

```
set -- abc def $(date >&2) ghi'jkl
```

which would end up with `abc` and `def` as two distinct parameters, and it would print the date to stderr, except that the lone single quote will cause a syntax error.

Using `eval` would be appropriate if you have something that's designed to produce output that's quoted for shell input.

---

If you're on Linux (and don't care about portability), you could do what roaima suggested in the comments, and use the util-linux version of `getopt` (without the `s`). It supports long options too, there's answers showing how to use it in [getopt, getopts or manual parsing - what to use when I want to support both short and long options?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/62950/170373) and in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29754866/6372809) and also [my answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/663806/170373).

Incidentally, with that `getopt`, you *would* use `eval`, since as a command, it's limited to producing just a single string as output, not a list like an array, so it uses shell quoting to work around the issue.

Comment: Yes, I change each `--context` to `-C`.

Comment: The code is intended ta address the portability problem.  Have used `getopt` before.

Comment: The biggest question is whether to use `eval` or not, because for the case of `getopt`, the use of `eval` seems necessary.

Comment: @khin, if you have something that's explicitly made to be a shell command, then you use `eval`. If not, then you don't. Your users probably don't want to enter args with spaces as `getopts_test "'foo bar'"`, instead of the normal `getopts_test "foo bar"`, and they'll probably also expect `getopts_test *` to work, even if some of the filenames contain whitespace (or shell special characters).

Comment: For my `getopts_test`, it like that using an array is a neat idea.  What do you think?  Customarily, I pass filename as non-option arguments by using the `break` command.

Comment: Would you be so kind to explain what commands would be explicitly shell command?  Am getting baffled with the terminology.  Could there also be some tangible code examples?

Comment: I agree that users would not want to use `getopts_test "'foo bar'"`.  They would want to run the command with `getopts_test "foo bar"`.  This directs me to use `set -- "${aggr[@]}"`.  When users pass `getopts_test -f -g 130 --colour="170 20" "foo bar" *` and one of the files has spaces (e.g. "un tit.pdf"), using eval, does split "un" from "tit.pdf".  I can see that using `eval` is not the right way to parse arguments when the developer decides to handle user arguments directly without using `getopts` or `getopt`.  Are we agreed on these points @ilkkachu ?

Comment: You are correct.  Using `getopts_test -f -g 130 --colour="170 20" "foo'bar"` yields `bash: unexpected EOF while looking for matching '.  bash: syntax error: unexpected end of file` when using `eval set -- "${aggr[@]}"`.  Whereas the problem does not occur with `set -- "${aggr[@]}"`.

Comment: @khin, one way to look at it, is that a shell command is a single string, while what results from it after quote processing is conceptually an array (or list, if you will). The command `ls 'foo bar' blah` gets converted to the array (`ls`, `foo bar`, `blah`). What the user initially gives as command, e.g. `getopts_test ...` is a string, but even before the function runs, that gets converted to an array. The elements of that array being (`$1`, `$2`, ...) inside the function. Then, you already have an array, and there's no need for the string->array conversion any more.

Comment: But `getopt` explicitly does an array->string conversion, _just for the purpose_ of it being converted back to an array, and only because it's not possible to directly return an array from a command substitution. (The output of a command is a stream of bytes, so just a single string, no structure inherently. That structure needs to be built with delimiter characters, e.g. the colons in `/etc/passwd` delimiting the fields. Just those aren't general, you can't have a colon in a value if the colon is the delimiter. Shell quoting _is_ general and easily available with `eval` for use with `getopt`)

Comment: And of course in general we could use `eval` in something like `eval "$(date +"hour=%H min=%M sec=%S")"` which would ask `date` to print a string that looks like `hour=13 min=39 sec=55`, which we'd then know would be useful as a command to the shell if we want those values assigned to the three variables. But we wouldn't use `eval "$(date +"%H:%M:%S")"` because the output `13:39:55` wouldn't be useful as a command. So we just do `time="$(date +"%H:%M:%S")"` instead. The point is that we'd only use `eval` if the output is designed to look like a command line, like one we'd write on the prompt.

Comment: And yes, the single quotes and spaces are what the extra `eval` would mess up

Answer (score 0):

You can parse `--foo`-style long options with the `getopts` builtin by adding `-` as a short option taking an argument to the optstring, and retrieving the actual long option from `$OPTARG`. Simple example:

```
while getopts :sc:-: o; do
    case $o in
    :) echo >&2 "option -$OPTARG needs an argument"; continue;;
    '?') echo >&2 "unknown option -$OPTARG"; continue;;
    -) o=${OPTARG%%=*}; OPTARG=${OPTARG#"$o"}; OPTARG=${OPTARG#=};;
    esac
    echo "OPT $o=$OPTARG"
done
shift "$((OPTIND - 1))"
echo "ARGS $*"
```

which you can then use as either `script -c foo` or `script --context=foo`.

If you also want to have the long options validated just like the short ones, and also accept abbreviated forms, you need something more complex. There is not much wisdom in over-engineering a poor shell script like that, but if you want an example, here it is:

```
short_opts=sc:
long_opts=silent/ch/context:/check/co   # those who take an arg END with :

# override via command line for testing purposes
# if [ "$#" -ge 2 ]; then
#   short_opts=$1; long_opts=$2; shift 2
# fi

while getopts ":$short_opts-:" o; do
    case $o in
    :) echo >&2 "option -$OPTARG needs an argument" ;continue;;
    '?') echo >&2 "bad option -$OPTARG" ;continue;;
    -)  o=${OPTARG%%=*}; OPTARG=${OPTARG#"$o"}; lo=/$long_opts/
        case $lo in
        *"/$o"[!/:]*"/$o"[!/:]*) echo >&2 "ambiguous option --$o"; continue;;
        *"/$o"[:/]*) ;;
        *) o=$o${lo#*"/$o"}; o=${o%%[/:]*} ;;
        esac
        case $lo in
        *"/$o/"*) OPTARG= ;;
        *"/$o:/"*)
            case $OPTARG in
            '='*)   OPTARG=${OPTARG#=};;
            *)  eval "OPTARG=\$$OPTIND"
                if [ "$OPTIND" -le "$#" ] && [ "$OPTARG" != -- ]; then
                    OPTIND=$((OPTIND + 1))
                else
                    echo >&2 "option --$o needs an argument"; continue
                fi;;
            esac;;
        *) echo >&2 "unknown option --$o"; continue;;
        esac
    esac
    echo "OPT $o=$OPTARG"
done
shift "$((OPTIND - 1))"
echo "ARGS $*"
```

then

```
$ ./script --context=33
OPT context=33
$ ./script --con=33
OPT context=33
$ ./script --co
OPT co=
$ ./script --context
option --context needs an argument
```

Comment: Does `getopt` also take a leading colon?  Could I check for `:` and `?` with `getopt` as well?

Comment: Might want to use `${OPTARG%%=*}` in the first one too (with double `%%`). The second one has something wrong with recognizing invalid options, e.g. `--xyz` comes up as `xyzsilent` (and `--sil` comes up as `silsilent` too). But you did say it wasn't properly debugged anyway. Might be easier to just drop support for abbreviated long options.

Comment: What is the purpose of  a leading `:` with `getopt(1)`?  Why does it shut up error messages?