# How to mix plain arguments with flagged arguments in bash scripting?

Tags: bash, shell-script, arguments, getopts

for instance, gcc accepts the input file without any flag and the output file with the `-o` flag in:

`gcc input.c -o output.out`

or

`gcc -o output.out input.c`

I am creating a random password generator bash script, the user should be able to specify the number of special chars, lowercase chars and uppercase chars using the `-s`, `-l`, `-u` flags respectively. They should also be able to specify the length of the password without any flag.

example usage:

`./randompassword.sh -s2 -u2 -l3 16`

should mean a password with 2 special, 2 uppercase, 3 lowercase chars and a length of 16.

I am able to parse the flags using `getopts` like so:

```bash
while getopts s:l:u: flag
do
    case "${flag}" in
        s) special=${OPTARG};;
        l) lower=${OPTARG};;
        u) upper=${OPTARG};;
    esac
done
```

However I can't figure out how to get the length argument which does not have a flag.

I tried using `$1` but this argument should be able to be at any position in the command just like the gcc example.

Comment: Note that the standard POSIX behaviour is that options are taken only at the beginning, not after any non-option arguments. So e.g. `ls foo -l` would take `-l` as a filename. The GNU tools relax that requirement (to the apparent ire of some) and you can get that behaviour in a shell script with the util-linux version of the `getopt` tool (without the s), but the standard shell builtin `getopts` (with s) doesn't support it in any shell I know of. So, in a shell script it's _easier_ if you can accept having to give the non-option length last.

Comment: See e.g. this for the use of the "advanced" `getopt`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/663806/170373. Also note that the "traditional" `getopt` versions can't handle arguments with whitespace cleanly (e.g. filenames like `my little poem.txt`), so they can be rather problematic. (but that's not a problem here when you're just passing numbers.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getopts` stops parsing the argument list as soon as it reaches a non-option argument.  That is, it returns success as it iterates left-to-right over the option arguments, then returns failure on the first non-option. So the proper use case is `put options and their arguments on the command line before any non-option arguments`.

The `getops` tutorials then show a `shift $((OPTIND - 1))` command.  The `while` loop iterates through the option arguments, then the `shift` removes them from the positional variables, leaving the non-option arguments (if any) in `$@`.

In code, using variables like those in tutorials:

```
while getopts ':s:l:u:' OPTION
do
  case "${OPTION}" in
    s) special=${OPTARG};;
    l) lower=${OPTARG};;
    u) upper=${OPTARG};;
   \?) echo "$0: Error: Invalid option: -${OPTARG}" >&2; exit 1;;
    :) echo "$0: Error: option -${OPTARG} requires an argument" >&2; exit 1;;
  esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))
# now the positional variables have the non-option arguments
echo "${1}"
```

With your example command (`./randompassword.sh -s2 -u2 -l3 16`), the output is `16`.

I added a leading `:` to the getopts string because it gives you "silent error reporting", which lets your script catch errors and issue a friendlier complaint.  That's the function of the extra two options I added to the `case` statement.

If the user broke the rule and typed option arguments **after** non-option arguments, the trailing option argument(s) would not be parsed in the `while` loop above.  It/they would appear in the `$@` array holding the remaining positional arguments.  If the user followed the guidelines and typed all the option arguments before the non-option arguments, the `$@` array will have the non-option arguments after the `while` loop and `shift` commands are done.

Per your concern about the order in which non-option arguments are typed, either your script expects these in a strict order, which your user must follow (else they get errors), or your script doesn't require a particular order to them, and must use other parsing methods to figure out how to use them.

But in my view, un-ordered arguments are why we have option letters.  The remaining arguments are ordered, else they would have option letters.  That's just my opinion, though.

Comment: Correction: `getopts` doesn't move non-option arguments to the end, or rearrange the arguments in any other way. To use `getopts`, options *must* be given before non-option arguments on the command line. So if you run the script with `./randompassword.sh -s2 16 -u2 -l3`, `getopts` will only process the `-s2` option, and the `-u3` and `-l3` arguments will be treated as non-option arguments.

Comment: @GordonDavisson thanks for your correction.  I've rewritten my answer to fix the misinformation (which came from poor testing I performed a few years ago).

Comment: Looks good now!