# Is there a tool or macro processor capable of compactly expressing BASH CLI interfaces?

Tags: bash, shell-script, getopts

I am writing scripts with the following boilerplate CLI pattern:

```
usage(){
  echo "$0 yada yada"
  ...
  echo 
}
for arg in "$@"; do
  case "$arg" in
    '--help|-help') set -- "$@" '-h';;
    ...
  esac
done

OPTIND=1
while getopts 'h...' opt; do
  case "$opt" in
     'h') usage; exit 0;;
      ...
  esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))
```

Is there any way to compress or encapsulate this in BASH on linux with other tools, perhaps an additional dependency?

Comment: That sounds like a bad approach. If your script were `grep` for instance, `grep -e --help -- --help` is meant to look  for `--help` in the file called `--help`, but you would end up transforming that to `grep -e -h -- -h`. Also with the standard CLI interface `cmd  -help` is meant to be the same as `cmd -h -e -l -p` (or `cmd -h -e lp` if the `-e` option takes an argument, etc). See [getopt, getopts or manual parsing - what to use when I want to support both short and long options?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/62950) and many other Q&As here for approaches at parsing long options

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas grep requires commands searching for, for example, '--help' to be escaped, `grep '\-\-help'`, even after adding quotes, so this is beside the point, imo.  Yes, there are other ways, this is a simple one and I am looking for an even simpler way.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes, I am aware of that edge case -- if I define parameters `-h, -e, -l, -p` then a user could eventually stumble on a surprise.  I am probably not going to change things for now, since the goal is for the user to stumble on `help`.  If the edge case becomes an issue, I'll change it.

Comment: no.  `-` is not a regex operator so putting backslash in front of it yields unspecified behaviour. To `grep` for `--help`, you use either `grep -- --help file` where `--` marks the end of options or `grep -e --help file` or `grep -e--help file` where `--help` is the argument to the `-e` option.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I have had to escape backslashes with `grep` in cross platform scripts. Surely in some contexts you are right, but it's got nothing to do with my question.  In fact, I don't need to use `-- --help` to work with bash if I escape the dashes, and I don't need to use `--regexp` (`-e`) either.

Comment: You use backslash to escape regexp operators as in `grep '\.' file` to look for a literal `.` or to  introduce some other operators, like in `grep '\([[:upper:]]\{4\}\)\1'` to look for a repeated sequence of 4 uppercase letters. `grep '\-\-help'` is just plain wrong even if in most `grep` implementations it will do the same as `grep -e --help`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas nonetheless, I'll consider your feedback in the boilerplate I'm not sure I can qualify including due to its lack of brevity.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas " grep '\-\-help' is **just plain wrong** even if in most grep implementations it will do the same as grep -e --help" -- this feels like a matter of opinion and a rant.  Please stop defacing my question.

Comment: If you use util-linux `getopt` or other option parsing tools/library, then you don't need to worry about all that. It will also properly handle unambiguous long option abbreviation (like `--h` / `--he`) here assuming it's the only long option that starts with `h`/`he`) and `--input=foo` in addition to `--input foo` and `-ifoo` + `-i foo`, etc.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I'll explore getopt, thanks -- presuming it is not as ubiquitous as the `getopts` built-in